# How to create a model that assigns a time, employee, and equipment to a job?

Tags: java, quarkus, optaplanner, timefold

Context: This is my first time working with Timefold/Optaplanner, so I might have some incorrect understanding of everything.

I'm working on developing a Quarkus Timefold app using/modifying the food packaging example. The goal is to update the model to be able to assign a time, which would be based on the previous job, an employee with the required skill, and required equipment. My model currently has a Job and Line from the example, and I'm trying to add a new Employee class. However, I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The config
> (QueuedValuePlacerConfig(ValueSelectorConfig(jobs),
> ListChangeMoveSelectorConfig(ValueSelectorConfig(null), null))) has no
> entityClass configured and because there are multiple in the
> entityClassSet ([class org.acme.foodpackaging.domain.Line, class
> org.acme.foodpackaging.domain.Job]), it cannot be deduced
> automatically.

In the job class, I added

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employees")
private Employee employee;
```

and in the PackagingSchedule class, I added

```
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "employees")
private List<Employee> employees;
```

This is my employee class:

```
package org.acme.foodpackaging.domain;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;

public class Employee {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String operator;
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
    Set<String> skills;

    // No-arg constructor required for OptaPlanner and Jackson
    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(Long id, String name, String operator, LocalDateTime startDateTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.operator = operator;
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        this.skills = null;
    }

    public Employee(Long id, String name, String operator, LocalDateTime startDateTime, Set<String> skills) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.operator = operator;
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    // Getters and setters
    // ************************************************************************

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStartDateTime() {
        return startDateTime;
    }

    public Set<String> getSkills() { return skills; }

}
```

I believe this error is because the Job class, which was originally a PlanningEntity with no genuine planning variables, now contains a genuine planning variable. How do I correctly create this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message should be improved, but the issue is that currently `@PlanningListVariable` cannot exist with another `@PlanningVariable` or `@PlanningListVariable`. The variable defined by `Line` is a `@PlanningListVariable`, which means no other genuine variables can be defined (as noted in the docs: https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/modeling-planning-problems#planningListVariable

> Planning list variable does not yet support all the advanced planning
> features that work with the chained planning variable. Use a chained
> planning variable instead of a planning list variable, if you need any
> of the following planning techniques:
>
> - overconstrained planning,
> - planning entity difficulty comparison or planning value strength comparison,
> - exhaustive search,
> - partitioned search,
> - coexistence with another list or basic planning variable.

Converting the model to chained is not trivial; essentially, `Line` becomes a problem fact that acts as an anchor, and `Job` becomes a planning entity that points either to a `Job` or a `Line`. I recommend you look at the ordering picking quickstart (https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/order-picking) for an example of creating a chained model.